# Channel TCP is already registered but with Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, remoting

I have created TCP Client and Server using .Net remoting . When I call server from client i.e. at the line `RemotingConfiguration.Configure("App.config", true);`, I am getting error as

> Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: The channel 'tcp' is already registered.

I have made all the settings in config file. To resolve this issue, I gave unique name to the client application. Now, I am not getting error but when I send any data from client to server,nothing happens at server or client end. If I closed the server, I get error in client application as remoting server closes the connection , which is proper behaviour. So the issue is why nothing happnes at client or server end.

`RemotingConfiguration.Configure("App.config", true);` line is not giving me any error, but `server.Send("Hi")` does not give any response back to the client. Nothing displays on server.